# How do I make a jQuery dialog button with a hyperlink?

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

In jQuery//dialog you can make a button like this:

```
dialog({ buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } } });
```

Can I make this button with a hyperlink to somewhere instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook on the [beforeclose](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-beforeclose) event and navigate to the link you wish with `window.location.href = "NEW_URL"` or alike.